# Long tapped implementation in windows store app

Tags: winrt-xaml

is there any practice how to implement long tapped on windows store application, or just with `PointerPressed` and `PointerReleased` events ??? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you referring to the [Holding event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.holding%28v=win.10%29.aspx)?

```
Grid grid = new Grid();
grid.Holding += OnElementHolding;
```

Comment: that is exactly what I need, thank you .. I will vote for your useful answer but I have small reputation ...